# How do I remove this hashicorp ppa key?

Tags: apt, ppa, gnupg

This is the error I'm getting whenever I do sudo apt-get update or anything with apt.

This is the error

```
Err:2 https://apt.releases.hashicorp.com focal InRelease   
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY DA418C88A3219F7B
```

I've even went to:

```
/etc/apt/sources.list.d$ ls
```

But did not find anything related to hashicorp. How do I get rid of this annoying GPG key?

```
alessandro-strada-ubuntu-ppa-focal.list
alessandro-strada-ubuntu-ppa-focal.list.save
google-chrome.list
google-chrome.list.save
home:manuelschneid3r.list
home:manuelschneid3r.list.save
linuxgndu-ubuntu-sqlitebrowser-focal.list
linuxgndu-ubuntu-sqlitebrowser-focal.list.save
pgdg.list
pgdg.list.save
protonvpn-stable.list
protonvpn-stable.list.save
teams.list
teams.list.save
webupd8team-ubuntu-y-ppa-manager-focal.list
webupd8team-ubuntu-y-ppa-manager-focal.list.save
```

---

```
$ grep -r hashicorp /etc/apt --include="*.list"
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb [arch=amd64] https://apt.releases.hashicorp.com focal main 
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb-src [arch=amd64] https://apt.releases.hashicorp.com focal main
```

Comment: Run `grep -r hashicorp /etc/apt --include="*.list"` and show the result.

Comment: @N0rbert  Here is the result!
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb [arch=amd64] https://apt.releases.hashicorp.com focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb-src [arch=amd64] https://apt.releases.hashicorp.com focal main

Comment: @N0rbert please set your comment to an answer and I will accept it. I got the results and from that command and deleted it from sources.list.

Comment: Done, presented both methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two possible solutions:

- to continue using the mentioned repository - re-add its key (not remove) by commands below:

  ```
  sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys DA418C88A3219F7B
  sudo apt-get update
  ```
- to remove the mentioned repository - locate it by using command below

  ```
  grep -r hashicorp /etc/apt --include="*.list"
  ```

  and then remove it using any known method like

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository -r "deb [arch=amd64] https://apt.releases.hashicorp.com focal main"
  ```

  then run `sudo apt-get update` as usual.

Comment: Thank you very much! I can't explain how grateful I am. I had this problem for a very long time!! Finally fixed. Thank you!